# fitted GEV df parameters / different results for different packages (lmomRFA, lmom, extRemes, nsRFA)

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a GEV df using L-Moment method for annual maxima value, but when using different packages, the parameters of the fitted GEV distribution (Location, scale and shape) were not similar.

I used different packages and the odd one was `lmomRFA`, could any one help me to identify the problem?

here is sample of what I am doing :

```
install.packages("extRemes")
install.packages("lmom")
install.packages("lmomRFA")
install.packages("nsRFA")
library (nsRFA)
library (extRemes)
library (lmomRFA)
library (lmom)

amax_standard <- c (0.6274510, 0.7545455, 0.6521739, 1.5102041, 2.0937500, 1.0000000, 0.7094017, 1.0315789, 1.3207547)
amax_standard_matrix <- as.matrix(amax_standard)## The AMAX as a matrix

amax_standard_vector <-  as.vector(amax_standard_matrix) ## The AMAX as a vector
amax_standard_vector_order <- amax_standard_vector[order (amax_standard_vector)] ## The AMAX as an ordered vector

fit1 <- fevd(amax_standard_vector_order,type =("GEV"),method=("Lmoments")) #fittig EVD using the "extRemes" package

lmom <- samlmu(amax_standard_vector_order)  # calculating the L-Moment ratios for the region. This function deals with all the observation as one vector
fit2 <- pelgev(lmom) #fittig EVD using the "lmom" package

regdata <- regsamlmu(amax_standard_matrix, nmom = 4, sort.data = TRUE, lcv = FALSE)
colnames (regdata) [4]<- c("t") # to make the column name acceptable for the "regfit" function
fit3 <- regfit(regdata, "gev") #fittig EVD using the "lmomRFA" package
```

the first two functions which are in the `extRemes` and `lmom` packages give similar results for the GEV df estimated parameter while the third function which is from the `lmomRFA` package provides different answer.

Moreover, I tried to use different package, which is the `nsRFA` just to estimate the parameters and used the function `par.GEV` and I provided the function with the estimated l-moment ratios which are identical for all the packages and can be found in the variable `lmom` and `regdata`  to estimate the parameters and the results were similar to the `extRemes` and `lmom` packages, so what is the problem with the function in `lmomRFA`

```
check <- par.GEV (1.0777622, 0.2760841, 0.3553799)
```